# Is this question completely defined

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I saw this question on a page:

If $a$ is additive identity then:

a)$a+a=2a$

(b)$a+a=1$

(c)$a+a=a$

(d)$a+a=0$

I think the question is undefined,Here the intended answer is c) but I think the question is undefined since the set is not mentioned to which $a$ is additive identity

Update: I guess a), c) and d) can be the correct answers at the same time or is there an example of a group which only satisfies c)?

Comment: All four answers are true in the trivial ring.

Comment: How is b) true?

Comment: It's a joke. The trivial ring has $1=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an additive group $(G, +)$ you have a unique (additive) identity $e$. This elements satisfies that $e + g = g$ for all $g \in G$. In particular you have $e + e = e$.

Example: Think about the additive group $\mathbb{Z}$. Here $0$ is the identity because you indeed have $0 + n = n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. In particular you have $0+0 = 0$.

So it is pretty obvious that (c) is the right answer since this is the defining property. However, I agree that it might be confusing.

One could argue that (d) is the right answer because $0$ usually is the "symbol" we use for the (additive) identity, and so you would have $a = 0$ and so (d) would be right.

(b) definitely isn't the right answer because $1$ usually denotes the multiplicative identity.

(a) could be considered right since we usually take $2a$ to mean $a+a$ by definition.

Comment: You make the question more confusing!

Comment: @HashirOmer: The point is that the answer is pretty obvious. But I can see that it might seem confusing. I don't think that the question is worded well.

Answer (score 1):

The question is well-defined. In any group $(G,+)$ if $a$ is the identity then $a+x=x$ for all $x \in G$. Therefore when $x=a$ the result follows.

Comment: See Thomas answer!

Comment: Thomas's answer simply suggests that if we follow some conventions (like $2a$ means $a+a$ Or sometimes we denote $0$ as the additive identity) then there could be more than one answer. However this still does not make the question ill defined.

Comment: If there could be more than one answer in MCQ format then surely it is ill defined.